# clip the text with a circular region

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter

How to Make Transparent ellipse with text inside or replace the ellipse border with text?

**Replace Text with Border**

```
ellipse = QPainter(self)
ellipse.setOpacity(0.6)
ellipse.setPen(QtGui.QPen(Qt.darkGreen, 4, Qt.DashLine))    # Any way to replace 'DashLine with Text ?'
ellipse.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(self.window_bg), Qt.SolidPattern))
ellipse.drawEllipse(0, 0, self.ellipse_width, self.ellipse_height)
```

**Text inside Ellipse**

```
ellipse = QPainter(self)
ellipse.setOpacity(0.6)
ellipse.setBrush(QBrush(QColor('#000000'), Qt.SolidPattern))
ellipse.drawEllipse(0, 0, 300, 300)
ellipse.drawText(10, 10, 'Random Text')
```

[image]

Comment: You could show a picture of what you want to get.

Comment: You could explain what you want, besides what is self?. What does the image have to do with what you want?

Comment: GIMP ;)
Photo Editor

Comment: self is QMainWindow thats it.

Comment: Your comment is not clear, explain and answer my questions :-)

Comment: Image is the end result of what i want to achieve by code

Comment: Where is the text in your image?

Comment: Random String the green lines
Background is the opacity
but the line is not going to hide. it is visible outside of the ellipse. that is the main issue

Comment: thank you, Who ever down vote this question althouse after all the codes and clear example.

Comment: The problem is your explanation, what I understand is that you want to cut some part of the text that is outside the circular region. Am I right?

Comment: sorry sir if its so hard.
yes you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a `setClipPath()`:

```
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        window_bg = "#0011ff"
        ellipse_width, ellipse_height = self.width(), self.height()
        r = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, ellipse_width, ellipse_height)
        text = "Stack OverFlow :-)"

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addEllipse(r)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setClipPath(path, QtCore.Qt.IntersectClip)
        painter.setOpacity(0.6)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor('#000000'), QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.darkGreen, 4, QtCore.Qt.DashLine))    
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(window_bg), QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawEllipse(r)

        # draw text in random positions
        for i in range(100):
            x = random.randint(0, self.width())
            y = random.randint(0, self.height())
            painter.drawText(x, y, text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: is there anyway to `setOpacity` in loop for random value like `setOpacity(round(random.random(), 2))`. 
I am getting error the Painter not active

Comment: @KrishnaTorque the error that you point out is caused when you try to use it in QPainter without setting a device or you are using QPainter outside the paintEvent, that is not due to opacity